# how do I handle conflicting function names between my antlr grammar and target language

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, antlr4, name-conflict

I have a grammar that contains function names called eval and round, these are already functions in python and when I try to generate the listener using:

> antlr4 -listener -lib /src/grammar -Dlanguage=Python3 -o /gen
>   -no-visitor /src/grammar/Grammar.g4

I get the following:

> error(134): Grammar.g4:138:0: symbol round conflicts with generated
>   code in target language or runtime error(134): Grammar.g4:174:0:
>   symbol eval conflicts with generated code in target language or
>   runtime error(134): Grammar.g4:62:3: symbol eval conflicts with
>   generated code in target language or runtime error(134):
>   Grammar.g4:134:3: symbol round conflicts with generated code in target
>   language or runtime

I can't simply change eval/round to a different name, because I'm writing a clone of a different dls.  Is it possible to create a namespace or work around this issue another way without changing my grammar language syntax?

Comment: If you want to write a clone of an existing dsl, then why do you need to put restrictions on the _rule_ names (not the keywords in your dsl)? Rule names are only important in your post processing steps, not for any client code.

Comment: Maybe also post your grammar. At least the lines that cause the error (i.e. something around line 138 for instance).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something that might solve your problems would be to prefix the offending rules with something like `r_`.

Example:

Current:

```
 eval:  'eval' anotherRule ';' ;
 anotherRule  : '1';
```

Changed:

```
 r_eval:  'eval' anotherRule ';' ;// change the rule name since eval is a reserved identifier in Python
 anotherRule  : '1'; // you don't have to change this rule, since "anotherRule" is most likely not reserved.
```

Note that 'eval' (the keyword your user enters in the dsl) is *not* changed!